# How to get normal vector from position vector function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have this equation:

```
f(t) = <x(t),y(t)>
```

What I would first like to do is figure out the normal vector at some point, t1.  How do I do this in MATLAB?

I would then like to figure out the angle between the normal vector and the x-axis in MATLAB.  If I can bypass finding the normal vector and just figure out the angle straight from f(t), that might be better.

it would be nice if there were some vector manipulation functions or something that I could use instead of manually taking the derivative of x(t) and y(t) and then finding the magnitude and all that stuff.  Any help would be great!

Comment: What do you mean by angle brackets? Is it parametric 2d curve? So, you can take one segment vector, which will be tangent vector, calculate an angle and add 90 degrees :)

Comment: yeah its a parametric 2d curve.  What do you mean by taking one segment vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dx` being the time derivative of `x`, i.e. `(x(t+1)-x(t-1))/(2dt)` (you can also use forward differentiation instead of central differences, of course), and `dy` the corresponding time derivative of `y`, you can find the angle between the normal and the x-axis easily from the vector [dx,dy], since its normal is just [-dy,dx].

Assuming n-by-1 arrays `x` and `y` with the coordinates, you do this as follows:

```
%# take the time derivative
dx = (x(3:end)-x(1:end-2))/2;
dy = (y(3:end)-y(1:end-2))/2;

%# create the normal vector
nvec = [-dy,dx];

%# normalize the normal vector
nvecN = bsxfun(@rdivide,nvec,sqrt(sum(nvec.^2,2)));

%# take the arc-cosine to get the angle in degrees (acos for radian)
%# of the projection of the normal vector onto the x-axis
angle = acosd(nvecN(:,1));
```

Comment: How accurate would this be? If I understand it correctly, this will give me an array of normal angles based on the t values I use to get the Nx1 vectors x and y.  What I would like to do is just specify one t value and get one angle between it and the x-axis.  It would seem a little excessive to calculate a ton of angles when I only need one of them.

Comment: I edited your algorithm to only calculate one angle.  Also, you forgot to square root the sum of nvec valuse so I added that in.  I was mainly wanting to know if MATLAB had functions that would do this for me but doing it this way also works.

Comment: @user972276: it appears the edit didn't go through, so I fixed the `sqrt` part. Thanks for spotting it! I'll leave the solution for all elements, since it should be fairly trivial to change it to work on a single angle only. Also, the calculation will be more accurate the more finely spaced t is.